# How to remove temp file in ansible using copy module

Tags: linux, ansible, adhoc

I'm using adhoc command for example

```
ansible some_group_of_hosts -m copy -a "src=/some_local_file
dest=/remote_path/"  -u someuser --become-user root --ask-pass
--ask-become-pass
```

After copy in the remote host. I found temp files in the directory ~/.ansible/tmp

How to remove this temp directory on remote host? 
Using another module like "commmand" ? In the reference of copy ansible module i did not found about remove temp file after copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/.ansible/tmp` is a "working" directory for Ansible on remote host.
As far as I know, it is not supposed to be removed.
For each task Ansible creates `~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-12345.1234.12345` directory and then cleans up only `ansible-tmp-xxx` subdirectory, and not "root" working directory.

You can change this remote path with [remote_tmp](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#remote-tmp) setting or with environment variable, like:

```
ANSIBLE_REMOTE_TEMP=/tmp ansible some_group_of_hosts -m copy -a "src=/some_local_file dest=/remote_path/" -u someuser --become-user root --ask-pass --ask-become-pass
```

This will force Ansible to work in `/tmp` and not create `~/.ansible/tmp`. But there's a risk of someone intercepting temporary data inside common `/tmp` directory.